# How to export files from a dmz servers

Tags: linux, rpc, mount, dmz

I want to export files (using NFS) from dmz servers.
Output of showmount command is fine on the same server. But it gives an error on other server connected in the network.

error is  "

clnt_create: RPC: Unknown Host

"
NOTE: I can do ssh connection to dmz server.

Comment: If you can SSH, u can also use SFTP which is file transfer protocol over SSH connection ( winSCP is an example of a window utility that doing that)